# What do you call a play when the offensive line is on the side?

Tags: american-football, terminology, formations

I saw recently in some video a play where only two guys, namely one who snaps and other one who catches a snap, were between the hash marks, but the offensive line was on the side of the line of scrimmage. It looked a bit weird, so I'm curious what kind of play it is, and what are its advantages and so on.

Does anyone know the name of this play?

Comment: See also: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/A-11_offense

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [swinging gate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Swinging_gate_%28American_football%29) formation, as you described, has the entire offensive line on one side of the center and quarterback, with perhaps only one wide receiver on the other side of the center.  It is pretty rare, and the advantages are surprise and the fact that you have a lot of blockers on one side for a running play if you don't need many yards.  The biggest disadvantage is that your quarterback is completely unprotected on one side, so the quarterback needs to get rid of the ball in a hurry.

Comment: The reason to have a wide receiver on the other side of the center is that otherwise the center must be an eligible receiver, as he would be the outermost line player on that side. I'm not actually certain whether or not that's legal.

Comment: It's legal as long as the "center" reports as an eligible receiver for that play.

Answer (score 1):

Got it! It is called swinging gate.

Comment: Welcome to Sports SE. Feel free to [accept](http://sports.stackexchange.com/help/accepted-answer) your (or another) answer.